# Alter the data frame to compute hourly values from the daily values in r

Tags: r, datetime, session, dplyr

I am working on analyzing a delivery unit. I have total number of packets delivered by a unit crew in a day aggregated by session. 
First column defines `Date`, second column indicates `Session_start` time, third column indicates `Session_end` time, fourth column indicate total deliveries done in that session `packets` and fifth column indicates session length `Diff_Time`. I just added `Session_Type` to indicate difference between sessions.

```
Data Frame: df1
Date        Session_start  Session_end  Packets  Diff_Time Session_Type
7/01/2016   00:00:00       03:00:00     6000     3         NIGHT
7/01/2016   04:00:00       06:00:00     5000     2         MORNING
```

Now I would like to convert above data which is aggregated according to session into hourly data as follows:

```
Data Frame: df2
Date        Session_start  Session_end  Packets      Diff_Time Session_Type
7/01/2016   00:00:00       01:00:00     2000(6000/3)     1         NIGHT
7/01/2016   01:00:00       02:00:00     4000(cumsum)     1         NIGHT
7/01/2016   02:00:00       03:00:00     6000             1         NIGHT
7/01/2016   03:00:00       04:00:00     6000             1         NIGHT
7/01/2016   04:00:00       05:00:00     8500             1         MORNING
7/01/2016   05:00:00       06:00:00     11000            1         MORNING
7/01/2016   06:00:00       07:00:00     11000            1         MORNING
.
.
7/01/2016   23:00:00       24:00:00     11000            1         MORNING
```

Total `Packets` in the day = 11000(6000+5000), which should be cumulative sum in reformed data frame `df2` at the end of the day.

Could any one point me towards the right direction to take this forward?

Comment: Is one hour the smallest unit of measurement of a session's length? Or can it go down into minutes? If one hour is the smallest unit, you can simply iterate through the hours of a day and for correlate that hour with the aggregate data.

Comment: @Vidur Yes, hour is the smallest unit of measurement of a sessions length.

Comment: @Vidur How is the date formatted mm/dd/yyyy??